# Publicar na playStore

Tags: android, google-play

Olá, 
Eu tenho um app na play store publicado. É possível publicar uma versão desse app com o mesmo ID porém com uma chave de assinatura diferente ?

Answer (score 1):

Com o mesmo ID você não vai conseguir, o id mais precisamente o package do projeto, é o identificador único do seu app, pode ter aplicativos com o mesmo nome mas não com o mesmo package. Estou presumindo que você perdeu a key store do app, neste caso você vai ter que mudar o package, consequentemente vai mudar o ID do app. Isto implica também que vai ser um app diferente para a play store